# List of Figure to title case

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I convert the List of Figures to title case? I tried used `stringstrings` package (which provides `\capitalizetitle` command) but my following patchcmd is not working.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@figure}{#1}{\capitalizetitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What is `title case`? Upper case? What do want to convert? The title `List of Figures` or each entry in the Lof?

Comment: Title case is :  "Block diagram of system" becomes "Block Diagram of System"

Comment: @mms: Why should `of` then still be lowercase?

Comment: This requirement came from my thesis format approval process

Comment: Prepositions are not capitalized. some examples are here http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm

Comment: tell them to stop being silly and look at the content of your thesis not play at being typographers?

Comment: True :( but I would like to get done with it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle historically I've found it easier to change LaTeX than to change other people

Comment: @mms: Regardless this is useful or not -- `l@figure` is the wrong command to patch

Comment: just use `\caption[Block Diagram of Systems]{Block diagram of systems}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried MakeUppercase and it worked but if I call the command from another package it is not working

Comment: My opinion is that this requirement is simply absurd: why should the caption in the list of figures be different from the one in the main document? Who knows? There's no real way to get “title case” back from the uncapitalized text; just some hacks that are not guaranteed to work. If you have to fight against silliness, just provide both texts as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\caption[Block Diagram of Systems]{Block diagram of systems}
```

It is a pointless requirement not worth spending coding time on spending time on:-) and doing it automatically is tricky requiring lists of words such as `of` to skip, and skipping over math mode or anything else that may come in a caption.

`\caption` allows you to specify the LOF text separately so you may as well just use that facility.